# Groovy Collect List of Lists

Tags: list, collections, groovy

I have a list of lists similar to this:

```
[[NAME:JFK, ENUMBER:E12365576], [NAME:Connor Moore, ENUMBER:E12365575]]
```

I know that if i do:

```
data.collect {s -> s.eNumber}
```

I get:

```
["E12365576", "E12365575"]
```

What I want to end up with though is something like:

```
["E12365576 JFK", "E12365575 Connor Moore"]
//Or, If possible something like below
["E12365576 (JFK)", "E12365575 (Connor Moore)"]
```

I've been looking and haven't found something similar to help me figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data.collect {s -> "$s.ENUMBER ($s.NAME)" }
```

or, more precisely

```
data.collect { "$it.ENUMBER ($it.NAME)" }
```

by using implicit `it`

Comment: I didn't know I could do this. Thank you so much